# Android Layout symlink/reference in another layout-XXX folder

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet

i'm currently updating my app for tablet layouts, for one of my fragments, i have one layout for phone portrait and one for phone landscape. 
on tablets i want the same layout as the phone portrait layout for both, portrait and landscape. for that to work, currently i have to copy the layout from layout/ folder(phone-protrait) to my layout-sw600dp folder. is there a way to achieve this behaviour without the need to copy the whole layout file?

for drawables i found this some time ago

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:src="@drawable/some_drawable"/>
```

is there something similar for layouts?

Thanks in advance :))

---

**UPDATE 1:**

found a possible solution here http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters

i have to put a xml in values-sw600dp

```
<resources>
    <item name="main" type="layout">@layout/mylayout</item>
</resources>
```

i have not yet tested i but i think this would work!

---

**UPDATE 2:**

after testing this, i have to say it does not work... i think the issue is that i want/need to use `<item name="main" type="layout">@layout/main</item>` what would be some kind of circular reference, i get `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment` :((